# vue.js "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

I know this is a common question, but I have been going through my files now so many times without being able to the locate the error.
I am getting this error when I try to route to my components in my navigation menu.

My app.vue file:

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar 
      :nav-links="navLinks"
    />
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
export default {
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  data: () => ({
    navLinks: [
      {
        text: 'Home',
        path: '/home'
      },
      {
        text: 'About',
        path: '/about'
      },
      {
        text: 'Contact',
        path: '/contact'
      }
    ]
  })
}
</script>
```

My Navbar component (This is where the error happens)

```
    <template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="{link, index} in navLinks" :key="index"
                @mouseover="hover = true"
                @mouseleave="hover = false">
                <router-link :to="link.path">
                    {{ link.text }}
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['navLinks'],
  data(){
    return {
      hover: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your rout config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li v-for="{link, index} in navLinks" :key="index"...
```

should be

```
<li v-for="(link, index) in navLinks" :key="index"...
```

As it's now (destructured), link refers to a `link` property inside the object, not the object itself. Additionally, `index` is probably undefined, since the navLinks objects probably don't have an explicit property `index`. Therefore Vue might also complain about using invalid indexes in `v-for`.

Since you're only using the `path` prop, you could actually use destructuring, like this:

```
<li v-for="({ path }, index) in navLinks" :key="index"
  @mouseover="hover = true"
  @mouseleave="hover = false">
  <router-link :to="path">
</li>
```

---

Another, unrelated note: `hover` property is currently being shared across all navLinks. If you expect it to somehow be related to the currently hovered element, yo uhave to save that separately (probably inside the navLink itself).

---

As for `:nav-links="navLinks"`, what you've done is not only perfectly legal, but the recommended way of doing it (it's according to the HTML spec). Using `:navLinks="navLinks"` relies on Vue's HTML parser, which converts it to `nav-links` behind the scenes - inspect the HTML element and you'll notice it).

If you want to get into the details, you could have a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/1162) on the subject. The result was: use either, but if you use `camelCase` it will be inconsistent with the rendered markup. If you use `kebab-case`, it will be consistent with rendered markup, so you won't have to deal with this difference when writing tests, for example, should you ever need to select elements by their attributes (jest converts `camelCase` to `lowercase` - hence it's inconsistent with the rendered markup, so the tests start passing/failing based on whether `mount` or `shallowMount` is used. Goes without saying, that's not really a good testing setup. )

The same exact discussion goes for using `<SomeComponent />` vs `<some-component />`. While both work, using first needs to be addressed when writing tests if you need to select stubbed subcomponents.

Besides, [vue/attribute-hyphenation](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/attribute-hyphenation.md) (the way you did it) is part of the following vue linting presets:

- plugin:vue/strongly-recommended
- plugin:vue/vue3-recommended
- plugin:vue/recommended

Comment: I see the mistake now. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A prop in the Navbar component is named **navLinks** but you access it outside as **nav-links**.
This should work:

```
:navLinks="navLinks"
```

Incorrect syntax for v-for with **{}**. Use **()**:

```
li v-for="(link, index) in navLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done two mistakes here.

one is:

```
 <template>
   <div id="app">
    <Navbar 
     :nav-links="navLinks"
    />
   <router-view/>
  </div>
```

Here you are binding with different name`(nav-links)`, you should keep same name with which you are binding data and the name inside the props`(navLinks)`.
Both names should be same.

Second one:

`v-for="{link, index} in navLinks"`

The syntax is wrong, the correct syntax should be

`v-for="(link, index) in navLinks"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. =)